# Switch callout text boxes on and off?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, layers, layouts

In my ArcMap project I’ve added text to the map in callout boxes to identify certain districts. Is it possible switch these on and off like the data layers? I don't want them to show in everything I export.

Comment: if an answer is helpful to you, please mark it as answered.  This goes for all of the questions you've asked over the last few days.  It will help you get better answers if people see you are making the best answers as such.  More info here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

If you have added the labels inside of your data frame, you can turn them on and off.  Here are a few ways to know if your labels are inside or outside of your data frame.

- **If you are in Data View** and you can see the labels, they are inside of your data frame.
- **If you are in Layout View**, first notice if you are working inside or outside of your data frame.  If the edge of the data frame is hatched, you are working inside of it.  It is is a solid line, you are working outside (ie. on top) of it. (Double click to go inside the data frame).
  You will only be able to select your labels when you are working in the same "space" that they are (either inside or outside of the data frame).  So if you can select, move, and edit your labels when you are working inside the data frame, your labels are also inside the data frame, and vice versa (if you can only select, move, and edit your labels when you are outside of the data frame, then they are also outside of the data frame.)

**If your labels are inside of your Data Frame, you can turn them on and off using the following method.**  Go to the Data Frame Properties window, and then to the Annotation Groups tab.  Uncheck the box by the annotation group you'd like to turn off (most likely the "Default" group name if you added the labels manually as text boxes.  If you add them by converting a layer's labels to annotation, then they will be listed in there as separate layers.

[image]

**If the labels are outside of your data frame, you cannot use this method to turn them on and off and you will have a few options.**

- Move your labels inside of your data frame.  To do this, select them all and right-click to Cut them.  Now double click inside your data frame to go inside the data frame and Paste them.  If you are lucky, they will all come in in the right place.  Otherwise, you'll need to manually move them to the correct locations.
- The other method to turn them on and off for different maps is less elegant if you're doing it many times.  Basically just select all of the labels and move them off of your map to "turn them off" (just moving them off the map display).  To "turn them back on" select them all and move them back on top of your map.  I'd recommend the 1st method unless the cutting and pasting does not work right.

The next time to add labels to a map, you can alleviate some of this if you Label your map based on attributes in the shapefile and then convert that text to annotation.  There is more detail on that at the following link: 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s80000001r000000.htm

If you want to add labels that aren't attributes of your data (so you can't use labeling), you can still add labels to an annotation group.  See this article (the part about Active Annotation Targets): 
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000008000000

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a novice so I apologize if I'm asking stupid questions! How do I convert the callout text boxes to annotation? How do I put the callout boxes inside the data frame?

Comment: No problem - this is something I found really confusing when I started with ArcMap!  I'll edit my answer to add some information on this.

Comment: @MikeFallopian If this answered your question, please click the green check near the voting arrows to mark it as "answered."  More info here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour